# Understanding the mask function in python

Tags: python

Hi Can someone please tell me the meaning of the following code

```
df.mask(df.sub(df.mean()).div(df.std()).abs().gt(2))
```

What I'm trying to do is replacing the outliers with NaN values. This is what I found but I'm not so clear what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of chained method calls.

Basically, it calculates the mean of each column of `df`, then subtracts this mean from the elements in the corresponding columns. Then, it calculates the standard deviation, and divides by it, again column-wise. Finally, it masks (converts to `nan`) all values greater than 2.

This process is known as "standardisation" - converting values into a multiple of their distance from the mean, in terms of the standard deviation. Here, presumably, we consider all values more than two standard deviations outliers, and remove them from the dataset.

However, perhaps something like this, which mixes operators and method calls, might be more readable...?

```
df.mask(((df - df.mean()) / df.std()).abs() > 2)
```